# Hiding Admin from System Preferences Account Tab

Tags: macos

Is there any way to hide an administrator account not only from the login screen but also from the system preferences/account tab? I'm pretty sure it doesn't appear on my MacBook Pro but on my iMac it does..

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5017?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) is Apple's official help doc on the matter.